# How to save relationship data in different tables by form_for with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two tables:

```
a. people
   id | name
b. cards
   id | person_id | number
```

app/models:

```
# app/models/person.rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cards, foreign_key: :person_id
end

# app/models/card.rb
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :people
end
```

Now I want to save both person and card record in one page:

```
# app/views/people/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(person, url: path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  # How to do here about card model?

  <%= f.submit 'Submit %>
<% end %>
```

Then how to make a relation source so I can save the two records at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) helper:

```
<%= form_for(person, url: path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.fields_for :cards do |card_form| %>
    <%= card_form.text_field :number %>
    ...
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit 'Submit %>
<% end %>
```

**Update** In order to use this form with your model, you should modify your person model:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cards
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cards
end
```

In your controller:

```
def person_params
  params.require(:person).permit(cards_attributes: [:id, :number])
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Then how to do in controller? Is it necessary to do the save in different controllers(app/controllers/people.rb, app/controllers/cards.rb)?

Comment: You can use single controller PeopleController for this

Comment: I wrote this in my create method in my controller: `@person.cards.build(number: params[:person][:cards][:number])`. It can save data to database, but is it good?

Comment: I updated my answer on how to use it in controller. Please read link for `fields_for` with detailed information.